# Automapper is setting the private fields without using the setter

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

We have a bit of code that checks in the setter if the existing is null/empty (and does something based off that).  Then it moves on and does the set of the private variable to what `value` is.

This caused us a bug when we set the object using AutoMapper.  When the setter is called for the first time, the private field already has the value in it (somehow).

I put together a small sample program that shows what I am trying to show.  `myPrompts` is the private variable that is already set when `set` for `Prompts` is called:

```
void Main()
{
    var orderContract = new OrderedTestContract{Prompts = new List<PromptContract>{
            new PromptContract{SomeValue = "Test1"},
            new PromptContract{SomeValue = "Test2"},
            new PromptContract{SomeValue = "Test3"}            
        }};

    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<OrderedTestContract, OrderedTest>();
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<OrderedTestContract, IOrderedTest>()
        .ConstructUsing(Mapper.Map<OrderedTestContract, OrderedTest>);//.As<OrderedTest>();

    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PromptContract, Prompt>();
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PromptContract, IPrompt>()
        .ConstructUsing(Mapper.Map<PromptContract, Prompt>);//.As<Prompt>();

    Console.WriteLine("About to map");    
    IOrderedTest order = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IOrderedTest>(orderContract);
    Console.WriteLine("Done Mapping");
}

public class OrderedTest:IOrderedTest
{
    private List<IPrompt> myPrompts = new List<IPrompt>();
    public List<IPrompt> Prompts 
    {
        get { return myPrompts;}
        set 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  About to set prompts.  Pre-count: " + myPrompts.Count);
            myPrompts = value;            
            Console.WriteLine("  Prompts set.  Post-count: " + myPrompts.Count);
        }    
    }
}

public interface IOrderedTest
{
    List<IPrompt> Prompts {get; set;}
}
public class Prompt: IPrompt
{
    public string SomeValue {get; set;}
}
public interface IPrompt
{
    string SomeValue {get; set;}
}
public class OrderedTestContract
{
    public List<PromptContract> Prompts {get; set;}
}
public class PromptContract
{
    public string SomeValue {get; set;}

}
```

This outputs:

```
About to map
    About to set prompts.  Pre-count: 3
    Prompts set.  Post-count: 3
    About to set prompts.  Pre-count: 3
    Prompts set.  Post-count: 3
Done Mapping
```

Where it writes out the "Pre-Count" the myPrompts variable should be empty or null, but it already has the mapped values in it.

**How/why is this already populated?  Without calling the setter?  Is Automapper doing something with the private variables? If so, what?**

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the (very complete, thank you) example that you have posted using AutoMapper 4.0.4.  Is there some other code that could be accessing this before your test, such as an IoC Container?  In fact, the setter should never be called in your example since nothing creates an instance of OrderedTest.

Comment: @DavidL - Odd.  I ran it using LinqPad.  There was no other NuGets in the LinqPad query.  I will go upgrade the AutoMapper version to the latest and test again.  (It is using the version in our application).

Comment: I also ran your code in linqpad and even modified the code to include a ctor in OrderdTest.  It is never hit with what you have so something must be modifying or instantiating the class outside of your example.

Comment: @DavidL - Even more odd.  When I updated to version 4.0.4 it does not call it at all.  The `As` option is not picked up (to use `OrderedTest` for `IOrderedTest`)

Comment: That would probably be the issue then.  In previous versions of Automapper (probably pre-4.0.x), I'm guessing that it is actually creating an instance when creating your mapping, which is why you already have an object.  That sounds like a bug, which is probably why it is no longer occurring in the newest version.

Comment: @DavidL - I updated the source to use the previous way of mapping interfaces (before `As<>` was added).  This creates the error still.  (Actually it calls the setter twice for some reason.)  The `As<>` missing is a known bug in 4 and is planned to be fixed in 4.1.0.  (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/887)

Comment: I can reproduce it with version 3.3.1 quite easily, although I don't yet understand the behavior.  Looking through the source I haven't found anything that jumps out as to why it initializes the backing field.

Comment: Even crazier, reflection acts as you would expect it to.  My new best guess is that after first pass AutoMapper caches the object and creates a new one under the hood, replacing your original object with the property and field already set.  I'd love some input from someone from the project :)

Comment: @DavidL - I would too.  Maybe I will post this as a bug if I get nothing here.